# Change of variable in a summation with the floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, change-of-variable

I'm currently trying to find the result of this sum

$\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor\sqrt{i}\rfloor$

using a limited subset of sum "properties" that you can see here

[Allowed sum properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioHr0.png)

I used to do a lot of variable change in my calculus class and I'm trying to apply the same approach here using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uyAbA-C0uU) video as a guide

With let z = $\lfloor\sqrt{i}\rfloor$ I obtain the following sum (which is great as I could use the second property to find the result)

$i = 1: z = \lfloor\sqrt{1}\rfloor = 1$

$i = n: z = \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$

$\sum_{z=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} z$

Which I know is a mistake already because with n = 7 the first summation gives 7 and the second gives 3...
It's really probably a dumb mistake but I'm unable to find it.

Comment: The most important thing to notice is that if $m^2 \le i < (m+1)^2$ then $m \le \sqrt i < m+1$ and $[\sqrt i] = m$.  So $\sum_{i= 1}^n[\sqrt i] = \sum_{i=1}^3 1 + \sum_{i=4}^8 2 + \sum_{i=9}^{15} 3 + ...... + \sum_{i=m^2}^{(m+1)^2 - 1} m + ..... +\sum_{i=K^2: K^\le n < (K+1)^2}^n K$.  Can you continue.